# ubuntu install latest redis through ppa source

Tags: ppa, launchpad, redis

How could I install the latest redis-server through `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/redis`

I know how could install via `ppa`, but I don't know the url in this source .

Comment: What are your system specs?

Answer (score 0):

I am running Redis Labs Enterprise Cluster on my ubuntu Desktop. You can get it from:
[RLEC](https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise-downloads)

Please make sure that you are running Ububtu Desktop 14.0.4 only as the installer checks the version and simply returns back if the version is not compatible. It doesn't work with 15.10.
Once you get the tar.gz file - gunzip and untar it and then run the install.sh. Installation is very smooth and at the install it will tell you the URL where you can access the cluster